# How has Christianity influenced Hindu thought or practice?

Tags: christianity

What are examples of Hindu philosophy or practice being influenced by Christian thought, tradition, or practice (e.g. the [Brahmo Samaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmo_Samaj))?

Comment: Brahmo Samaj is not inspired by Christianity. They worship Brahman as per Vedas!!!

Comment: While it is true that there have not been large-scale impacts on the practice of Hinduism, there are communities of practice (especially in southern India) that have syncretized Hindu and Christian practices, e.g. by adding Jesus Christ to the pantheon. There are also things like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Ashram_Movement.

Comment: @senshin, thanks for your comment. Could you post that as an answer to the question?

Comment: Christian Ashram movement remains a Christian sect & not a Hindu sect. It was rather Hindu influence on Christianity and not the other way around.

Comment: @Anirvan If I get some more time to research the topic, I will. At the moment, my understanding of the interaction between Hinduism and Christianity is too fragmentary to really be useful.

Comment: As senshin pointed, there some organizations in southern India which use the names like Ashram and Dhyan. People are mainly attracted by such names.  Actually nothing is related to Hindu culture in those organizations. They used to tell, your savior has come, join in Christianity, escape from disbelief and misdeeds. The soul purpose of these organizations is Conversion.

Comment: Hindu religion is the oldest one. All other religions came out of it and with passage of time became separate religions

Answer (score 12):

Hinduism was not influenced by Christianity, rather it predates it. 
The 2 religions have completely incompatible world view.

There has been lots of effort put on by European Indologists to paint Vivekananda & Ramakrishna Mission to be copying Christian values of service & charity.

The Book [Indra's Net](http://indrasnetbook.com/) proves with philosophical & historical evidence that Vivekanda's ideology of seva originated from the Upanishads & not from Christianity. The basis of Seva(service/charity) is "Tat Tvam Asi" principle which means "you are that". You are same as your neighbor. The basis for this philosophy predates Christianity.

Comment: It's not reasonable to categorically say that there are absolutely zero examples of Hindu philosophies being influenced by Christianity — in fact it's hard to make _any_ categorical statement about a religion as diverse as Hinduism!

The question itself gives the example of the Brahmo Samaj. Brahmo leaders like Keshub Chandra Sen were very explicitly influenced by Christianity.

Comment: @Anirvan Perhaps what you're looking for is how Christianity has influenced modern Hindu sects or movements. The downvote isn't appropriate -- your question needs to be more refined.

Comment: Why do you say that the two religions have completely different world views? [Just recently](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/can-islamic-beliefs-be-accommodated-in-the-light-of-vedantic-beliefs) there's been quite a lot of discussion on this site about how accepting Hinduism is of other religions (i.e. Hindus believe all other religions are equal paths to God). Why would you call Christianity incompatible?

Comment: @Akshay, it cannot be an one way road. Hinduism accepts truth can have different versions while Christianity claims exclusivity. I.e it does not accept Hindu version of truth. This is also part of the difference in the world views.  Also see my answer for another question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/881/can-one-be-a-hindu-that-worships-through-christ/905#905

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental difference in religious styles of the West and the East.

Western religions (Islam and Christianity) have a digital view of the world. Creator and Creation.

Hinduism in its core believe the Created and Creation are one and the same.

Western religions believe in preaching. Hinduism believes in understanding and experiencing.

Western religions have this view of "Not my way, or the highway". Hinduism treats "My way", "Highway", "Some other way", "No way" as different ways.

Western religions could have been influenced by Hinduism, since the texts and scriptures existed at the time the Western religions came up. Hinduism is unlikely to have been influenced by Christianity.

Cultural influences of the West on the East, did occur, but religious influences were very limited, as the two religions have markedly different styles of approach towards God.

Comment: "Hinduism in its core believe the Created and Creation are one and the same." Not true--the complete negation of this statement is the foundation of Dvaita Vedanta.

Comment: Not exactly, Brahman could exist without the universe, but the Universe could not exist without Brahman.

Answer (score 0):

Namaste

Hinduism has vast literature and every component of "universe" is explained in detail and to go through such literature, one requires many births and then to understand it many many more.

Christianity & Islam are preachings of a single person i.e. single awakened person, within a very very limited life span

To make mountain of such preachings and to talk of "entire universe" with a single book, is far fetched.   Gita is also a small book, however, the depth of sacred text mentioned in GITA is far superior to Bible and / or Islam.

Nothing in Hindu society nor practises of any hindu individuals is influenced either by Christianity or Islam.

Saint / Sage Ramanuja himself "converted" shudras to brahmin, saying there is no casteism defined in hinduism (i.e. no cultural discrimination of any type)

Comment: You should cite sources.  By the way, Ramanujacharya wasn't against the caste system.  He just thought that if you've performed Sharanagati or surrender to Vishnu, then your varna dharma or caste duties no longer apply.  But he thought that those who haven't performed Sharanagati still have to follow their varna dharmas.